# How can I make this step the same level as the floor?

Tags: concrete, floor, foundation, renovation, leveling

This might be the top of the foundation wall.  I believe this doorway didn't exist originally, leads to an addition room.  This step is a trip hazard.  I got a flooring company quote for this tile but they won't level this step.  I was thinking of using some kind of concrete grinder (no experience with this) but am worried about doing the bottom corners.  I think the raised part is about 1" tall when the tile is removed.[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Either grind/remove it or have a wide(2 or 3 inch) ramp added  Your toes will like you at least.

Comment: If the raised spot on the step is between the original part and an addition, I will bet you it is the footing... a pretty important item. It is a toss of the dice whether it is good to remove or not. If it was, it would change the rise of the other side, where there would be 2 different rises there, also a trip hazard. Removing 1 inch of a potential 8" thick footing, may not be an issue, especially since the  foundation wall is gone too.